Movie or SciFi drama I watched in the 00s
this scene I remember, on some planet, intergalactic war begins, someone VIP from earth is betrayer and accomplice of alliance, and now he is stuck on the planet that will be destroyed, all life form will be eradicated, and he said to this alien lady(look like human, all of them are mammals) that look what she brought to him, and she said to him to not worry, everything will settle down.
Next scene is in a field, people are trying to escape that planet, and one warship ( with soldiers) come to rescue some of them. since there were many, they decided to play lottery so people who are drowning from pot can get with them, problem is that this traitor is well-known personality, and he is not selected to be safe, and solder on that ship recognized him and told to other soldiers that he will switch places with him since it is really important that significant personality will be saved. 
Show was in English, and I remember seeing it in the early 2000s.
I hope you understand my plot explanation as English is not my first language. 

Its the reimagined Battlestar Galactica mini series, which was was a backdoor pilot to the full series that followed. A scifi political drama in space. It is a reboot (maybe) of the original series.
You described the escape from Caprica (one of the 12 colony planets) following the Cylon bombing. It happens because someone gives them the security codes to the defense systems of the Colonies forty years after the Human Cylon war. The Traitor is Baltar. The "Alien" is Number Six, a human form (skin job) Cylon, a robotic race, or Head Six, the angel that took Sevens form for reasons not evident until the final episodes.
The ship is a Raptor, a drop ship. The soldier was Helio. Baltar is taken because he's the colony wide foremost leading scientist, and they believe he'd be important in fight back against the Cylon attack. They were kinda right.
The Ship that the Raptor goes to is the titular Battlestar Galactica, a war era ship, a relic without modern security systems, which allowed it to escape the onslaught caused by Baltar.

Props to you!!! I love BSG but I was unable to connect the poster's statements with it until after reading your answer!!

Oh Cde, I love you, thank you. Do you know, some website where can I watch this ? I dont know if it is allowed to ask that, but it would be nice.

@SSimon UK netflix (you could use a proxy to avoid the geo-lock) or more recently Hulu. As well as less um, legit sites that you can Google for.

@cde found, I dont understand yet why doctor is seeing that girl? did they influence by changing his brain? or he is just crazy?

@ssimon. It's a spoiler if I tell you. If you want to know, Google head six
